# Localization of the model with a tree-like structure

Tags: python, django, localization, django-mptt

I'm new to python/django development and I'm stuck.

I'm making a project on Django 4.0.4.
I have a tree table in a SQLite database.

In the admin panel, I configured it using the **DraggableMPTTAdmin** class from **mptt**. I also want to localize the fields of this table.

**QUESTION**: How can I combine the **DraggableMPTTAdmin** class with the **TranslationAdmin** class?

---

my_app/models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey
from django.db.models import CharField

class NonStrippingCharField(CharField):
    """A TextField that does not strip whitespace at the beginning/end of
    it's value.  Might be important for markup/code."""

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['strip'] = False
        return super(NonStrippingCharField, self).formfield(**kwargs)
    
class CategoriesAndAreas(MPTTModel):
    name = NonStrippingCharField(max_length=150, unique=False)
    is_category = models.BooleanField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
    
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name
    
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['name']
        
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category or area"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories and areas"
```

my_app/translations.py

```py
from modeltranslation.translator import register, TranslationOptions
from .models import CategoriesAndAreas

@register(CategoriesAndAreas)
class CategoriesAndAreasTranslationOptions(TranslationOptions):
    fields = ('name',)
```

my_app/admin.py + DraggableMPTTAdmin

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import DraggableMPTTAdmin
from .models import CategoriesAndAreas

admin.site.register(CategoriesAndAreas, DraggableMPTTAdmin,
    list_display=(
        'tree_actions',
        'indented_title',
        'is_category',
    ),
    list_display_links=(
        'indented_title',
    ),
)
```

[The table has a tree structure with the ability to drag and drop.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkcnL.jpg)
[The form for editing an element contains an extra field.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2YgC.jpg)

my_app/admin.py + TranslationAdmin

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin
from .models import CategoriesAndAreas

admin.site.register(CategoriesAndAreas, TranslationAdmin)
```

[The table structure is linear.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpihc.jpg)
[Everything is fine here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joUmj.jpg)

my_app/admin.py + TranslationAdmin + DraggableMPTTAdmin

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import DraggableMPTTAdmin
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin
from .models import CategoriesAndAreas

class TranslationCategoriesAndAreas(CategoriesAndAreas, TranslationAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(TranslationCategoriesAndAreas, DraggableMPTTAdmin,
    list_display=(
        'tree_actions',
        'indented_title',
        'is_category',
    ),
    list_display_links=(
        'indented_title',
    ),
)
```

> ERROR:
> class TranslationCategoriesAndAreas(CategoriesAndAreas, TranslationAdmin):
> TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Comment: What do you want to achieve in this line __class TranslationCategoriesAndAreas(CategoriesAndAreas, TranslationAdmin):__ ?

Comment: @Deepak Tripathi
I was triing to use the recommendations from documentation:
[TranslationAdmin in Combination with Other Admin Classes](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html#translationadmin-in-combination-with-other-admin-classes-1)

Comment: Deepak Tripathi
You have given me an idea!!!

Comment: hahahaha I think you will resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand how the admin panel works, that's why I had difficulties.
By trial and error, I came to the result. For an experienced developer, this would be easy...

my_app/admin.py + TranslationAdmin + DraggableMPTTAdmin

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from mptt.admin import DraggableMPTTAdmin
from modeltranslation.admin import TranslationAdmin
from .models import CategoriesAndAreas


class DraggableTranslationAdmin(TranslationAdmin, DraggableMPTTAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(CategoriesAndAreas, DraggableTranslationAdmin,
    list_display=(
        'tree_actions',
        'indented_title',
  
        'is_category',
    ),
    list_display_links=(
        'indented_title',
    ),
)
```